# Вывод значения функции

Tags: javascript, html

есть функция для вывода серверного времени

```
<?
echo date( 'Y m d ', time() );
?>
<b id="seconds">0</b>

<script Language="JavaScript">
var hours = <?php echo date("H"); ?>;
var min = <?php echo date("i"); ?>;
var sec = <?php echo date("s"); ?>;
function display() {
sec+=1;
if (sec>=60)
{
min+=1;
sec=0;
}
if (min>=60)
{
hours+=1;
min=0;
}
if (hours>=24)
hours=0;


if (sec<10)
sec2display = "0"+sec;
else
sec2display = sec;


if (min<10)
min2display = "0"+min;
else
min2display = min;

if (hours<10)
hour2display = "0"+hours;
else
hour2display = hours;

document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = hour2display+":"+min2display+":"+sec2display;
setTimeout("display();", 1000);
}
display();

</script>
```

Как мне вывести функцию display(); допустим в отдельном блоке div, для того чтоб я мог редактировать стили?

Comment: `<div id="seconds">0</div>`

Comment: Что конкретно вам нужно вывести, и при чем тут стили?

Comment: @Anamnian вывести время и дату, допусти я хочу изменить цвет текста , как мне это сделать?

Comment: `<style>#seconds { color: red; }</style>`

Comment: Разобрался со всем, спасибо